# How does the following Semaphore application in C works?

Tags: c, semaphore

This is psuedocode for task synchronization using a semaphore.
The operation involves a security check between transferring data.

```
Begin_Security_Check=create_semaphore(0);
Security_Check_Done=create_semaphore(0);

Task Security_Check
{
    while(true)
    {
        wait_semaphore(Begin_Security_Check);
          (*actions check data*)
        signal_semaphore(Security_Check_Done);
    }
}

Task Download_Data;
{
      (*actions to download data from WAN to router buffer*)
    signal_semaphore(Begin_Security_Check);

    wait_semaphore(Security_Check_Done);
      (*actions to download data from router buffer to LAN*)
}
```

---

In the notes I'm reading :

**s= create_semaphore(v);**
Where v=0 or 1

**wait_semaphore(s);**
If s=1 then set s=0 and allow the calling task to proceed, otherwise suspend the calling task.

**signal_semaphore(s);**
If there is no task waiting for semaphore sthen set s=1 otherwise resume any task that is waiting on semaphore s.

---

But this means `wait_semaphore(Begin_Security_Check);` has a value of 0 because `Begin_Security_Check=create_semaphore(0);`,  right? This means it should suspend the calling task ?
The first two definitions have `create_semaphore(0);` -- that means they're both the same?

I'm really confused, can someone please go step by step and explain how this pseudo code is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially we create two semaphores, each with a value of 0.

Now I'm guessing these two `Tasks` are somehow started on separate threads - in particular, `Task Security_Check` seems to loop forever, so it must be sitting in its own thread waiting for work.  When it calls `wait_semaphore(Begin_Security_Check);`, it will pause until someone signals `Begin_Security_Check`.

Now someone calls `Download_Data`.  It does whatever it needs to do to download the data, and then signals the semaphore `Begin_Security_Check`.  This wakes up the `Security_Check` thread, which then proceeds to do whatever it needs to do and signals the `Security_Check_Done` semaphore.  Meanwhile, the downloading thread will have gone on to `wait_semaphore(Security_Check_Done);`, causing it to pause until the `Task Security_Check` signals that semaphore.  So it will not proceed until the security check is finished.

Comment: Okay so this means, the code stops at `wait_semaphore(Begin_Security_Check);` until its signaled, hence it goes on to the next piece of code under `Task Download_Data;` .. right ? and after that the `(*actions to download data from WAN to router buffer*)` code runs until it signals `signal_semaphore(Begin_Security_Check);` , which then goes back to the first loop and runs `(*actions check data*)` and so on .. is this correct ?

Comment: That's basically the flow - but keep in mind that you have two separate threads of execution here, so it's not like execution somehow transfers from `wait_semaphore(Begin_Security_Check)` to `  (*actions to download data from WAN to router buffer*)` as if were a `goto` of sorts - someone has to start up `Task Security_Check` on a thread and call `Task Download_Data` on another thread.

Comment: So if no one starts `Task Download_Data`, will the code just wait at `wait_semaphore(Begin_Security_Check);` ?

Comment: Until something signals that semaphore (it doesn't have to be D_D, although in the code presented, that's the only place it happens), that call to wait_sempahore won't return.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that, if Security_Check gets to wait_semaphore before anything else happens, it will wait.  But notice what the first thing that Download_Data does (wrt semaphores): it signals that very semaphore, which would wake up Security_Check.  This is EXACTLY the kind of synchronization that you want.

Comment: Also, each call to create_semaphore() creates a new semaphore, so the two AREN'T the same.